Replace with Pandas
I have a dataframe created with pandas from a csv file with field called host where I'm trying to use replace to remove some off this field.
When I use just replace it removes the text wherever if finds it but I only want it replaced/removed if it starts with the stated text.
After doing some research I thought the code bellow would work but it doesn't so I was wondering if someone could help me.
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^(BBC-)', '')
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^(ITV-)', '')
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^(CHANNEL5-)', '')


can you provide an example with your expected input/output?

In newer versions of Pandas, str.replace now has regex=False by default; this was True in previous releases.

try changing the replace to:
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^BBC-', '', regex=True)
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^ITV-', '', regex=True)
df['host'] = df['host'].str.replace('^CHANNEL5-', '', regex=True)    

